# React testing library how to use waitFor with a Promise

Tags: react-testing-library

I understand how to use `waitFor` with a simple function, but I can't imaging a good use case to use it with a Promise. Do you have an idea? TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitFor` will wait for the callback to not throw an error, so you can always `await` the promise inside `waitFor`.

```js
await waitFor(async () => await new Promise(...))
```

Btw most of the time you can just `await` the promise without the need for `waitFor`. A good example would be the `findBy` methods:

```js
await findBy('#someId')
```

Comment: TY @Toni for your answer. I think I understand now what is the purpose of using `waitFor` with a promise: This method may call the promise **multiple times** until it resolves. (I was thinking that the promise will be called only one time.)